# How to open date picker explicitly in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to open ionic date time picker when I click a button(or when i set value in one picker it should open another date time picker).

Comment: could you provide some code you've implement? please consider to check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Nice workaround:

1. add datetime component and hide it.
2. attach a reference to it.
3. make sure to display the value manually since the picker is hidden.

code example attached.

html:

```
<ion-col (click)="datePicker.open()" width-50>
    <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>

    <div>
        {{ selected.toDate() | amDateFormat:'DD' }} {{ selected.toDate() | amDateFormat:'MMM' }}, {{ selected.toDate() | amDateFormat:'YYYY'}}
    </div>

    <ion-item no-lines hidden="true">
        <ion-datetime  #datePicker
            text-center
            (ionChange)="dateChanged($event)"
            displayFormat="DD MMM, YYYY" 
            [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

.ts:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { DateFormatPipe } from 'angular2-moment';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './awesome-compo/awesome.html',
    pipes: [ DateFormatPipe ]
})
export class AwesomeCompo {
    private selected: any = moment();
    private date: any = moment().toISOString();

    @ViewChild('datePicker') datePicker;

    dateChanged(date) {
        const { day, month, year } = date;
        this.selected.year(year.value).month(month.text).date(day.value);
    };
}
```

For a detailed answer: [Full answer](https://blog.jarmemori.es/tech/2016/09/14/display_ionic_datetime_picker_programmatically.html)